# Div containing vue app has no elements in it, when it clearly does

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've just started learning Vue.js, and I'm following the Vue Mastery beginners course right now. For some reason, my div with id app, contains no elements when I inspect it on Chrome, when clearly it does in my html code. I also found that when I comment the script tag that contains my main JavaScript file, the html elements appear on the page. Please help!

main.js

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            cart:0,
            product: 'Soks',
            image: './assets/images/socks_blue.jpg',
            inStock: true,
            details: ['50% cotton', '30% wool', '20% polyester'],
            variants: [
              { id: 2234, color: 'green', image: './assets/images/socks_green.jpg' },
              { id: 2235, color: 'blue', image: './assets/images/socks_blue.jpg' },
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addToCart() {
            this.cart += 1
        },
        updateImage(variantImage) {
            this.image = variantImage
        }
    }
})
```

index.html

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="nav-bar"></div>

  <div class="cart">Cart({{ cart }})</div>
  
  <div class="product-display">
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img v-bind:src="image">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
        <p v-if="inStock">In Stock</p>
        <p v-else>Out of Stock</p>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="detail in details">{{ detail }}</li>
        </ul>
        <div v-for="variant in variants" :key="variant.id" @mouseover="updateImage(variant.image">{{ variant.color }}</div>
        <button class="button" @click="addToCart">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Import App -->
<script src="./main.js"></script>

<!-- Mount App -->
<script>
  const mountedApp = app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

A screenshot of index.html
[image: Screenshot of index.html output, with inspector open]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app needs to be mounted (oh, I see you're doing this now...):

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
...
})
app.mount("#app");
```

And there is an unclosed parentheses in the template:

```html
@mouseover="updateImage(variant.image)"
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/xqeyd5tb/) if you'd like one